# Django form field errors in templates

Tags: django, templates, forms, field

Django templates allow access to field errors via field.errors.as_ul.  In Python, however, field has no attribute errors.  How does this work?

My particular problem is that I tried serializing the forms (and the errors) and on the deserialization everything works in python, but errors don't show up if I ask explicitly for them via field.errors.as_ul.  They do show up via field.errors, though: basically, the list of strings shows.

Can someone explain this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are actually two separate classes for fields - the field elements you declare in your form, and a `BoundField` class which is automatically created by the form and which contains any bound data and errors.

Comment: Great hint, looks like the templates work with BoundFeild's.  OK.  That kind of answers my first question.  My primary concern (the lack of as_ul) turned out to be my bug:  I had an ErrorDict whose values were regular lists rather than ErrorList's.